# Difference between PORT and LATCH on PIC 18F

Tags: port, pic, microchip, pic18

I already read the datasheet and google but I still don't understand something.

In my case, I set PIN RC6 of a PIC18F26K20 in INPUT mode:

`TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1;`

Then I read the value with `PORT` and `LATCH` and I have different value!

```
v1 = LATCbits.LATC6;

 v2 = PORTCbits.RC6;
```

`v1` gives me `0` where `v2` gives `1`.

Is it normal?
In which case we have to use `PORT` and in which case `LATCH`?

Comment: I believe basically LATs are for writing on them and PORTs for reading from them. You could also read from LATs but conditions apply.
Refer to the datasheet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The latch is the *output* latch onto which values are written.  The port is the voltage at the actual pin.

There are a few situations where they can be different.  The one that I've encountered most frequently is if you have a pin (accidentally) shorted to ground.  If you set the latch high, the latch will read high, but the port will read low because the voltage on the pin is still approximately ground.

Another situation leading to what you've described is when the port pin hasn't been configured correctly.  I (and everyone I work with) have spent many hours trying to figure out why our PIC isn't working to expectations, to eventually find out that we glossed over turning off the analog modules, for instance.  Make sure you go over the section I/O Ports -> PORT?, TRIS?, and LAT? registers in the datasheet.  You can get more info in the  [Microchip wiki page](http://microchip.wikidot.com/) which explains about reading the wrong value immediately after you write an output on a pin connected to a capacitive load.

That wiki page also explains:

> A read of the port latch register returns the settings of the output drivers, whilst a read of the port register returns the logic levels seen on the pins.

Also, here's a snippet from the I/O Ports section on the 18F14K50 (which ought to be the same as the rest of the 18F series):

> Each port has three registers for its
>   operation. These registers are:
>
> - TRIS register (data direction register)
> - PORT register (reads the levels on the pins of the device)
> - LAT register (output latch)

So in most situations, you will write to the latch and read from the port.

Comment: So if the PIN is in INPUT mode, what should I use? LATCH or PORT?
And if the PIN is in OUPUT mode, what should I use? LATCH or PORT?

Comment: INPUT = `PORT`, OUTPUT = `LATCH`

Answer (score 22):

I'll adapt [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/12532/938) from Electrical Engineering.

Let's use the picture from manual:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation]

When you write a bit in a I/O pin, you're storing this bit from Data Bus to the Data Register ([D-FlipFlop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29)). If TRISx of this bit is 0, so data from Q of the Data Register will be in the I/O pin. Write in LATx or PORTx is the same. See below in red:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation Write]

On the other hand, read from LATx is different of read from PORTx.

When you're reading from LATx, you're reading what is in the Data Register ([D-FlipFlop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29)). See picture below in green:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation Read LATx]

And when you read from PORTx, you're reading the actual I/O pin value. See below in blue:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation Read PORTx]

PIC uses read-modify-write to write operations and this can be a [problem](http://data.bolton.ac.uk/staff/ks3/ECE1011/2%20ProgrammableDevices/Lectures/I1readmodifywrite.pdf), so they use this shadow register to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I was confused about this PORT and LAT read and write. Thanks for pictorial representation of the read from PORT and write to LAT.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a useful summary from the datasheet.

11.2.3 LAT Registers
 
The LATx register associated with an I/O pin eliminates the problems that could occur with 
read-modify-write instructions. A read of the LATx register returns the values held in the port 
output latches, instead of the values on the I/O pins. A read-modify-write operation on the LAT 
register, associated with an I/O port, avoids the possibility of writing the input pin values into the 
port latches. A write to the LATx register has the same effect as a write to the PORTx register.

The differences between the PORT and LAT registers can be summarized as follows:

- **A write to the PORTx register
  writes the data value to the port
  latch.**
- A write to the LATx
  register writes the data value to the
  port latch.
- **A read of the PORTx
  register reads the data value on the
  I/O pin.**
- A read of the LATx
  register reads the data value held in
  the port latch.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I read the datasheet and this part but it doesn't answer the question: when i need to read the pin (input mode), should i use latch or port and when i need to write the pin (output mode) should i user latch or port.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's normal to read PORTx and LATx and occasionally find they have different values.

When you want to read whether some external hardware is driving a pin high or low, you must set the pin to input mode (with TRIS or the DIR register), and you must read PORTx. That read tells you if the actual voltage at the pin is high or low.

When you want to drive a pin high or low, you must set the pin to output (with TRIS or the DIR register); you should write the bit to the LATx register.

(Writing that bit to the PORTx register may *seem* to do the right thing: that pin will -- eventually -- go high or low as commanded. But there are many cases -- such as when some other pin on that port is connected to an open-collector bus -- that writing to one bit of the the PORTx register will mess up the state of the other pins on that port, leading to difficult-to-debug problems).

[Open Circuits: read before write](http://opencircuits.com/read_before_write)

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to regard the PORT values as read-only.  The LAT values may be read or written, but the value read will be the last value written, not the input value of the pin.

On older PICs, the LATx values didn't exist; the only way to write to a port was via the PORTx registers.  Curiously, some of the really old PICs, back from the General Instruments (pre-Microchip) days, supported LATx, but Microchip didn't add that feature until the PIC18x line.

Answer (score 1):

A write to the `PORTx` register writes the data value to the port latch.
A write to the `LATx` register writes the data value to the port latch.
A read of the `PORTx` register reads the data value on the I/O pin.
A read of the `LATx` register reads the data value on the port latch.

Use `LATx`: to write to an output pin

Use `PORTx`: to read an input pin

For all PICs with `LATx` registers, all INPUT must be from `PORTx` and all OUTPUT should be to `LATx`, which totally avoids the problem of flipping bits when you write to a single bit of the port.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced that writing on PORTx Ri (e.g. PORTC RC1) of PIC18F14K50 is ineffective when another PORTx Rj (e.g. PORTC RC0) was already set.
I observed a peek in the oscilloscope on PORTx Ri but I was unable to sustain the output.
This issue has vanished as soon as I was writing on LATx.

LATx writing looks mandatory on PIC18 and PORTx writing prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to write to LAT, read from PORT, the reason is when the port is used as output, bit operation of PORT will do read modify write instruction.

Read modify write Instruction have some pitfalls, based on the output capacitance (rise time of the port pins) which may set the port pins to wrong value, when two consecutive READ modify WRITE instruction is executed.

So always write to LAT and read from PORT (input pins)